# get single value from object array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, node.js, object

I know there are plenty of solutions to get a single value from an object array. But I thought there must be a way to directly access the values without a explicit function.

I have an array of users in nodejs which I send to the frontend and get it by `result.data`, but I only want to print in the console the objectName (s) of all users.

```
[{"objectName":"cn=anna,ou=user,ou=system",
"sn":["1"],
"cn":["test1"],
"objectClass":["top","inetOrgPerson","person","organizationalPerson"],
"userPassword":["password"],
"uid":["12345"]},

{"objectName":"cn=tim, ou=user,ou=system",
"sn":["2"],
"cn":["test2"],
"objectClass":["top","inetOrgPerson","person","organizationalPerson"],
"userPassword":["password"],
"uid":["125342"]}
]
```

Is there a solution? Something like `console.log(result.data.objectName)` ..?

Comment: not if you want to access more than one. Can't be done without a function

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
console.log(result.data.map(function(el){ return el.objectName }).toString());
```